# NETWORKDAYS function applied to a variable column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a set of data that I export every day to Excel. I am trying to write VBA code that will calculate the number of workdays it has been since our company received an order, with the count starting the day after the order was received.

The date received is in column B and I want column C to display the NETWORKDAYS function with regards to the date received and today's date. The problem I am having is that each day there are a different number of rows in my data export (i.e. some days we get more orders than others) so I wanted to write the code to apply to every C cell for which the B cell next to it contains data.

I'm not familiar with coding language and variables enough to get this to execute correctly.

For functionality right now, my current writing is:

```
Range("C2") = WorksheetFunction.NETWORKDAYS(Range("B2"), Range("$M$1"))-1
```

Obviously, this only applies the function to the first row where data is found, C2, but I wrote it to make sure I understood how to use the NETWORKDAYS function in VBA in the first place. I'm thinking I need some sort of IF/THEN statement or loop in order to apply this code multiple times until the last order is reached, but not sure how to get there. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Is there any reason you're not writing an actual formula to the cell? i.e. `Range("C2").Formula = "=NETWORKDAYS(...)"`?

Comment: When I export the data from my ordering software there is a redundant piece of data that exports into column C originally, so in an effort to clean up my table and not have large gaps in my worksheet I have some additional code written above the line mentioned above that deletes irrelevant information and shifts some columns around. I was mostly hoping to be able to include the function in the code to not have to stop and type it every day but if that is the only solution I can reach then I can deal with it

Comment: You can write a formula with VBA, no need to manually type it in. EDIT: the posted answer demonstrates this (though it converts the formula to a value with `.Value = .Value`).

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```vb
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet
With ws.Range("C2:C" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row)
    .Formula = "=NETWORKDAYS(B" & .Cells(1).Row & ",$M$1)-1"
    .Value = .Value  '(optional if you want to fix the values)
End With
```